What year was Navier-Stokes equations introduced?
In this video he is explaining what are Navier-Stokes equations. As I find these equations are evolution of Euler equations.
In this article they choose 1822. Do yo agree with this?
Who and when first time introduced below equations(dont have to be in same notation, content is important)?


Sounds pretty opinion based. Why does there need to be a year most-associated with a concept?

Read Anderson's brief history and decide for yourself. Navier introduced them in a memoir read in 1821 and published in 1822. Cauchy, Poisson, Saint-Venant and Stokes rederived them between 1822 and 1845, when Stokes linked them to many experiments revealing their practical significance. Reynolds averaged them in 1894, creating a framework for studying turbulence. Leray proved existence of weak solutions in 1934, Ladyzhenskaya of smooth 2D solutions in 1969, Millenium prize for smooth 3D was offered in 2000.

@Conifold In what year did the equations get the name "Navier-Stokes"?

Equations do not get named "in a year". People call them this and that, eventually one of the names becomes dominant. Google Ngram shows that "Navier-Stokes" started to be used around 1929. Millikan used it that year in On the steady motion of viscous, incompressible fluids, as did Prandtl in his lectures published in 1930 with English translation in 1934. It probably spread from there

@Conifold https://arxiv.org/pdf/2401.13669  Do you agree 1822 as "best" year of birth?

Contrary to Bistafa, the equation was "introduced by Claude-Louis Navier" in 1821, not in 1822, that is the year of publication. The "best year" label does not make much sense to me, it is "best" to say what happened when in less vague terms.

@Conifold Principia is written in 1686 and published 1687 but Newton discovered all this 20s years before(1665-1666), so from your logic more important is year of discover or year of publication?

From my logic, X is the year of discovery, Y is the year of submission, Z is the year of publication, etc. And "whatever is more than these is from the evil one." "Important" and "best" means different things to different people in different situations and for different purposes, they are unsuitable for discussing history.
